# DataGridView auto size height

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I size an datagridview in a C# winform to make use of all his allocated space?

I have allready used `gv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;` to auto size the gridview in width. Now I want to make use of the full height available so no background is visible.

When I'am schrolling all the way down to the last record in the gridview there is still an gray background visible.

My gridview is anchored right and resizing along with the form works also fine. I just wanted to get rid of unnecessary visible background.

The tip V4Vendetta gave me did the trick.

Comment: You could use the dock function.

Comment: Whats happens when you set `AutoSizeRowsMode` ?

Comment: Thanks when I set `gv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;` it will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Set anchor property of grid as **Top, Bottom, Left, Right** for all side expansion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dock, or for more precise control use the Anchor property. By setting Anchor to Left, Right, Top, Bottom the control will scale with the window. By setting Anchor to Right the control will move with the right border. By setting Anchor to Top and Bottom the control will scale vertically, but have a fixed width. Just experiment